# Regex to match two words in a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a string

> "13572_BranchInformationReport_2012-06-28.zip","13572_BranchInformationReport_2012-06-28.zip",0,"184296","`Jun 28`  1:30","/icons/default.gif"

What could be the Regex If i want to extract `Jun 28` from this string using c#.

Comment: with one string it's hard to find the pattern, I suggest string manipulation, you can for example explode your string with comma as separator, and get the 4th element

Comment: This is just a single string from an HTML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the format of the month name abbreviations you can use something like this:

`@"((Jan|Feb|Mar|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s[0-9]+)(?<!\s)"`

Comment: Cool, just make sure you change any months if they're displayed differently, Sept instead of Sep for example.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a CSV record. If so I suggest to use standard [string.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) function to  extract the single components and extract the date by trimming the token containing the date, regex should be used if there is no simpler way to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the structure of the string is always the same:

```
@".*\"".\"".*\"".\""([\w]+ [\w]+) .*\"".\"".*"
```

and then us the

```
match.Groups[1]
```